# How To Traverse and read specific value from DirectoryObject (MS GraphAPI in C#)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently fetching group details (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) using the following C# SDK sample:

```
var graphApiAuthProvider = new GraphAPIAuthenticationProvider();
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(graphApiAuthProvider);

queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
       new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var result = graphClient.Groups[$"{groupID}"].TransitiveMembers
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                    .Select("id,displayName,mail,mailNickname")
                    .GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This gives the group details result in **DirectoryObject** (Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject).
Each DirectoryObject object record is of type Microsoft.Graph.Group

Now I'm stuck as to how to read all the details like email, displayname etc. from this DirectoryObject.

How can we programmatically traverse and read this DirectoryObject (in above case the ***result*** variable)? The endgoal is to read and store specific properties in a separate list/variable?

Comment: For debugging put a break point after result.  You add a .ToList() to query you can easily see the results by hovering over the variable results.

Comment: @jdweng, Yes already tried this. But even if we do .ToList() the result will be converted in List<DirectoryObject>. Which brings back to my same question - how can we programmatically access and read properties from within DirectoryObject

Comment: You should be able to cast : result.Select(x => (Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject)x)

Comment: Ah yes! Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier. Since all of the records within this DirectoryObject are either of type Microsoft.Graph.Groups I did the following as you suggested:
result.Select(x => (Microsoft.Graph.Group)x);

Answer (score 3):

Cast the results list to a list of Groups:

```
var groups = results.Cast<Group>().ToList();
```

Or for more safety use OfType:

```
var groups = results.OfType<Group>().ToList();
```