# How can I turn a DirectoryObject into a Group?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of group names from the Microsoft.Graph API using the following method

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetGroupNames(List<string> groupIds)
{
    Microsoft.Graph.Groups.GetByIds.GetByIdsPostRequestBody requestBody = new()
    {
        Ids = groupIds,
        // Why do I need to specify that the type is group when I'm using a constructor in the Groups namespace?
        Types = new List<string> { "group" }
    };

    Microsoft.Graph.Groups.GetByIds.GetByIdsResponse result = (await graphServiceClient.Groups.GetByIds.PostAsync(requestBody))!;
    Group[] groups = result.Value!.Cast<Group>().ToArray();
    return groups.ToDictionary(g => g.Id!, g => g.DisplayName!);
}
```

`result.Value` is then a list of DirectoryObjects where each object has `ODataType` "#microsoft.graph.group".

From what I've seen on this website (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576917/22433209)) it should be possible to simply cast the `DirectoryObject`s to the correct type `Microsoft.Graph.Group`, but that does not work. This gives the message

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.DirectoryObject' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.Group'.
```

So how exactly am I meant to turn these DirectoryObjects into Groups?

Comment: it's better to use the `DirectoryObject`'s `AdditionalData` property to access the raw JSON response and then deserialize it into the `Group` type.

Comment: which version of SDK do you use?

Comment: @user2250152 Microsoft Graph 5.23.0, Microsoft.Identity.Web 2.13.2, Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient 2.13.3

Comment: @user2250152 Upgrading Microsoft.Graph to 5.24.0 fixed it

Comment: There was a bug in 5.23 related to DirectoryObject and Group: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2084

Comment: Wow that's specific. Mystery solved. Thanks! @user2250152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `Microsoft.Graph` from 5.23.0 to 5.24.0 fixed it. I believe these are the relevant nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.24.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.55.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.13.3" />
```

I don't know if this was a bug in 5.23.0 or if I had incompatible nuget packages installed, but whatever the case it works now.

Edit: Thanks to @user2250152 I now know this was a bug in 5.23.0. See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2084

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario,I'll iterate over each `DirectoryObject` in the response. If it has `AdditionalData` with `@odata.type` as `#microsoft.graph.group`, I'll convert the JSON into a `Group` object using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and add it to the `groupNames` dictionary!

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetGroupNames(List<string> groupIds)
{
    Microsoft.Graph.Groups.GetByIds.GetByIdsPostRequestBody requestBody = new()
    {
        Ids = groupIds,
        Types = new List<string> { "group" }
    };

    Microsoft.Graph.Groups.GetByIds.GetByIdsResponse result = await graphServiceClient.Groups.GetByIds.PostAsync(requestBody);
    
    Dictionary<string, string> groupNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var directoryObject in result.Value)
    {
        if (directoryObject.AdditionalData != null && 
            directoryObject.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.type", out var odataType) && 
            odataType.ToString() == "#microsoft.graph.group")
        {
            Group group = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Group>(directoryObject.AdditionalData.ToString());
            groupNames[group.Id] = group.DisplayName;
        }
    }

    return groupNames;
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. As it turns out you can just cast like I was trying to. You just need to not have 5.23.0 installed. Also ToString() just gives the type name, and even after correcting for that I get a string which couldn't be deserialised into a group. Also even if this work around did work I'd probably just use the dictionary because that's less hacky than what you're doing here.